# React. why can't I insert a component from a third party library?

Tags: reactjs

I have the latest version react react@17.0.1 and use the react-player library, import the player, insert it into the layout and get errors:

> ------- Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as
> React DOM) You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks You might have
> more than one copy of React in the same app
> ------- VM30105 react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the component: at Provider
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:14:20)
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior.
>
> ------- Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function.

As soon as I remove the Provider store = {store} /Provider wrapper everything works fine, which may be the problem, also when I try to add functional components I created, the same error occurs.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { rootReducer } from "../redux/rootReducer.js";

import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'


import { compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

function App() {
   
    return (
        <div>
          
            <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById("app")) {
    ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
}
```

Comment: Change `const app = (...)` to `const app = () => (...)`

Comment: : Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: oh yes sorry, overlook the ReactDOM.render, could you post your `rootReducer.js` too?